# Extremum Problem

Tags: optimization

[image]

> How big is the circle?

My first steps:

1. $ x^2 + y^2 =r^2$
2. $ f(x)=y=e^{-x^2}$

Substitute $y^2$ in $x^2 + y^2 =r^2.$
So, $x^2 + e^{-2x^2} =r^2$

Is this way correct? Because after calculating the first derivative $2x -4xe^{-2x^2}$  and so on my solution at the end is $x^2 = \dfrac {\ln(2)}{2}, $ and this is not correct.

Comment: What derivative do you get?

Comment: I´ve edited my text.

Comment: In the points of contact must be the derivatives equal.

Comment: What is the correct answer you have?

Comment: @LarsBaumann: It looks as though you may simply be mis-interpreting what you've got so far. Your result for $x^2$ isn't the radius of the circle. It's the square of the $x$ component of the intersection point. You still have to calculate $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ to get the radius, if that's what your question is asking.

Comment: Based on your comment to [Mostafa Ayaz’ answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2899654/265466), it appears that the problem is asking you to find the _area_ of the circle, not its radius.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is right. Clearly the circle and the curve meet at $(x,y)$ in first quadrant where $$x^2+y^2=r^2\\y=e^{-x^2}\\-2xe^{-x^2}=\dfrac{-x}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}$$which means that $$2y=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {r^2-x^2}}=\dfrac{1}{y}$$therefore $$y=\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}$$and $$x=\sqrt{\dfrac{\ln 2}{2}}$$which means that $$r=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\ln 2}{2}}\approx 0.9200943377$$

Comment: Should it not be $$y=\pm\frac{1}{2}$$ etc?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Mostafa's answer specifies that the point being considered is in the first quadrant.

Comment: The right answer for $r^2$ is $ \frac {\pi}{2} * (ln(2)+1)$ , but i can´t find a way to solve this.

Comment: @LarsBaumann That’s the _area_ of the circle, not its radius squared.